# PHP to get array_values from 2D array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2D array like

```
attendee_programs = [1 =>[100,101],
                     2 =>[100,101,102]
                    ];
```

I want to get `array_values()` and `array_unique()` but only for the *nested elements* (sorry, not sure what the terminology is) ...I.E.

```
programs = [100,101,102];
```

Is there a php function for this? or do I need to loop through and assemble it manually?

**Edit: All of the answers are very helpful and have shown me something new. Sorry I can only accept one.**

Comment: Maybe you want to flatten the array first, then use array_unique.

Comment: oh i think you are right. i will try array_values then array_unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($attendee_programs));
```

to get values of nested array.

```
array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($attendee_programs)));
```

to get unique values.

Comment: I accept this answer because it seems to be the least overhead and closest to intention for this case but the other answers are all relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a clever combination of array_unique, array_reduce and array_merge to achieve this:

```
$a = array_unique(array_reduce($attendee_programs, 'array_merge', []));
```

Doing this might be end in an array with some gaps in the indizes - if you need gaples array keys, you have to add array_values at the end

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

Comment: Add `array_values()` to reindex the array

Answer (score 1):

- [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)
- [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Solution:

```
function flatten($array)
{
    $rit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

    return iterator_to_array($rit, true);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(flatten($attendee_programs));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 101
    [2] => 102
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
$flat = array();
array_walk_recursive($attendee_programs, function($value) use (&$flat) {
    $flat[] = $value;
});
$flat = array_unique($flat);
```